# How to compare to different arrays in javascript/jquery and get back the columns with difference in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Since I don't know how this works very well and other questions such as:
[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)
or, [JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)
are completely different questions and after 1 and a half hours of scouring the web no results I am going to go and ask this question simply. Say you have two arrays `[1,2,3]` and `[1,4,1]`. Then how would you get a program to make our variable (say x) to be `[1,2]` (because column 1 and 2 are different if you count the first column as column 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [1, 4, 1];

var columndiff = [];

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1[i] != array2[i]) 
    columndiff.push(i);
}

console.log(columndiff);
```

**Note:** Here we are assuming that `array1` and `array2` has equal length

Comment: Thanks so much dude!

Answer (score 0):

ES2015 code:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [1, 4, 1];

const result = a.reduce((res, val, index) => { 
    if (val !== b[index]) res.push(index);
    return res;
}, []);

console.log(result); // [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this;

```js
var arr = [1,3,4,5,2,3],
    brr = [1,3,5,5,1,2],
    res = arr.reduce((p,c,i) => c !== brr[i] ? p.concat(i) : p,[]);
console.log(res);
```